# How to assign and change the value of a QString?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I would like to know how to assign and change the value of a `QString` variable. If I wanted to assign the `QString` value as `0`, how would I do it?

Comment: 0 - is a number. Do you really want to assign a number to string variable?

Comment: Yes I do. Is it possible to do so?? If so how???

Comment: Okay, but how to assign a normal qstring value?               QString description="you're on the right track";   will this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign any string to a QString as follows.

```
QString a="this is a string";
QString b="250"; //though this is a number it is in a string format now in the variable b
```

If you want to take it for calculations then a conversion is needed. Simply convert it to an `int`:

```
int i;
i=b.toInt(); // i holds the integer 250 now.
```

Do calculations and convert it back to a string before displaying it in a label or something:

```
i=(i*5)+650; //just a calculation.
a=QString::Number(i); // now i is converted to a string and assigned to a
```

Simply display it in a QLabel as follows:

```
ui->label->setText(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is important to note that `0` is an integer and QString is a...well QString.  I'm assuming you'd like to *convert* the `0` to a string first then assign that to the `QString`.   There a couple of ways to do this, the easiest is to just do:

```
QString s = "0";
```

If you are trying to assign an `int` variable to a string you can do:

```
int i = 0;
QString s("%1").arg(i);
```

The parameter in the first arg call will fill the places of `%1`, the second `arg` call fills the value of `%2`, etc.  `arg` will convert the `int` to a string.

To later change the value you can do:

```
QString s = "0";
s = "This value has changed to something else";
```

Comment: Lol! I'll do that. I'm new to this. :D